# Flutter Navigation push() and pop(), filling up the stack?

Tags: dart, flutter

Building an App in Flutter, I wanted to use the Navigation Drawer and added a few FlatButtons.
Every `FlatButton` has an `onPressed()` method where I do `Navigator.push()` moving to the desired page, which is working just fine.

I was wondering if this over time is filling up the memory because I am always pushing but never popping pages from the stack.
Always combining a `Navigator.pop()` with a `Navigator.push()` successively seems a little odd and far away from good practice.

Maybe someone can enlighten me about the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

This will indeed lead to potential memory issue. To solve this problem, you can pop unneeded routes. You could also add a custom `NavigatorObserver` to add a history limit.

example:

```
class HistoryLimit extends NavigatorObserver {
  final int limit;
  final history = <Route>[];

  HistoryLimit([this.limit = 42]);


  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic> newRoute, Route<dynamic> oldRoute}) {
    final index = history.indexOf(oldRoute);
    history[index] = newRoute;
  }


  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    history.add(route);
    if (history.length >= limit) {
      this.navigator.removeRoute(history.first);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    history.remove(route);
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    history.remove(route);
  }
}
```

Which you use by adding it here:

```
MaterialApp(
  navigatorObservers: [
   HistoryLimit(10) 
  ],
  ...
)
```

Comment: This snippet of code has caused my navigation to stop working after 10 clicks.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Flutter is telling me this:
`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2124 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.`

which in navigator.dart shows: 
`assert(() {
      debugPredictedWouldPop = !route.willHandlePopInternally;
      return true;
    }());`
after this method is run the navigation doesn't want to push anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Navigator.pop()` when you want the back button to navigate to the previous route. In this case, yes, the stack keeps filling up.

There are other methods though like

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/replace.html
- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html
- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html

that replace the current route by a new one.
This way you can't use the Android back button to navigate back through each previous route.

Comment: You could add some sort of history limit too

Comment: Do you mean https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LocalHistoryRoute/addLocalHistoryEntry.html ?

Comment: No I'm thinking of a custom `NavigatorObserver` that removes old routes on push

Comment: Ok, so basically what he is doing currently but a bit smarter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
Navigator
        .of(context)
        .pushReplacement(...
```

```
?
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of @Remi's anwer.
If this `this.navigator.removeRoute(history.first);` throws error:

```
!_debugLocked
is not true
```

Delay next navigator action

```
  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    history.add(route);
    if (history.length >= limit) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        this.navigator.removeRoute(history.first);
      });    
    }
  }
```

Navigator does not allow 'push', 'pop', etc from within a call to 'push', 'pop'.

Comment: Thanks. it works ! even removing the route in the middle of stack works.