# Flutter:How to logout from second screen

Tags: flutter

I'm using mysql to authenticate users in my app, and login/signup, and logging out works correctly when I logout from the home page directly following the login page, but doesn't work when I logout from a users page routed from the home page.

It is logged out on mysql_database, but the page won't go back to the login page immediately calling signout unless I hot restart.

following is my logout function:

```
Future<void> logout() async {
    print('logout started');
    final url = '${PurohitApi().baseUrl}${PurohitApi().login}/$sessionId';
    var response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': accessToken!
      },
    );

    var userStatus = json.decode(response.body);
    print(userStatus);

    if (authTimer != null) {
      authTimer!.cancel();
      authTimer = null;
    }
    print(userStatus);
    refreshToken = null;
    refreshTokenExpiryDate = null;

    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

In my root page, I have:

```
MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
    
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          ),
          home: Consumer<Auth>(builder: (context, value, _) {
            print("from material app");
            return value.isAuth
                ? const Welcomescreen()
                : FutureBuilder(
                    future: value.tryAutoLogin(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) =>
                        snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                            : const Adminlogin(),
                  );
          }),
          routes: {
            'viewPackage': (context) => const ViewPackage(),
            'users': (context) => const Users()
```

So if isAuth is false then it is not is not logged in, it should return back to the LoginSignUpPage.

following is my logout button where I am trying to redirect

```
ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: const Text("Logout"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that logs out and after it's completed it pushes navigates to the login page using `Navigator.pushReplacement` which wont allow the user to get back to the previous by using back button

Comment: Hope this helped if there is any doubt you can ask me here in comments and if it works you can let me know by  marking my answer correct

Comment: This will indeed lead to potential memory issue.so I am using `Navigator.pop(context);`[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111550/flutter-navigation-push-and-pop-filling-up-the-stack

Comment: I am facing error when I am using `Navigator.pushReplacement` Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.